# Как запустить скрипт под нужной версией php с консоли?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ispmanager

На сервере Debian7 и ispManager 5.85. Большинство сайтов работает в режиме cgi на разных версиях php. Нужно запускать скрипты по крону, или композер под соответствующей версией. Такая команда 
`php-7.0 /path/script.php` - не работает, сообщает:

```
-bash: php-7.0: command not found
```

Comment: а куда он у вас установлен, этот интерпретатор седьмой версии? вот оттуда его и запускайте, указав полный путь к исполняемому файлу.

Comment: ну он устанавливается из под ispmgr , а куда она его ставит не знаю. Ну хотя бы есть вектор куда копать, ато суппорт конкретно ничего не говорит.

Comment: *устанавливается из под ispmgr* — как и, вероятно, любая другая надстройка, призванная, якобы, облегчить жизнь новичку, эта программа, на самом деле, во-первых, тоже требует изучения, а во-вторых, скрывая якобы ненужное, создаёт неиллюзорные проблемы тем же самы новичкам.

Comment: @alexander нашел /opt/php70/bin/php

Comment: так напишите в ответе, как вы это вычислили. другим новичкам может помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/opt/php70/bin/php` для `linux Debian 8`.

Comment: пожалуйста отметьте Ваш ответ как решение - серая галка слева от ответа

Answer (score 0):

Для поиска интерпретатора php проще всего использовать утилиту `locate`.
Она найдёт все файлы php в индексе `updatedb` и выведет их.

```
locate -b '\php'
```